# launchctl: Dubious ownership on file (skipping) (Mac OS X)

Tags: mac, mysql, launchctl

I installed mysql recently and added its start command in my .bash file. But when I tried running the command, that's when I encountered this error:

> launchctl: Dubious ownership on file
>   (skipping):
>   /Users/newuser/Library/LaunchAgents/com.mysql.mysqld.plist
>   nothing found to load

Does anyone know what it is about?

Comment: See: [Why am I getting a “dubious ownership of file” error when Launch Agent runs my .plist file?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/3250/22781) at AD SE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this discussion](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=1418817), it may be a permissions issue with that .plist.

The article suggests:

> A chmod 644 on the plist (logged in as
>   whatever user the home directory
>   corresponds to), run launchctl again,
>   and you should be good.

In addition, I would suggest creating a copy of the .plist in question before changing the permissions.

Comment: I am having this issue as well. My permissions are however already set to 644.

Answer (score 0):

You've to correct the ownership (in some other cases permission or path) of your *.plist* file or force the loading by `-F`.

Here is snapshot from [launchctl.c](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/launchd/launchd-392.39/launchd/src/launchctl.c):

```
if (sb.st_uid != 0 && sb.st_uid != getuid()) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s: Dubious ownership on file (skipping): %s\n", getprogname(), path);
    return false;
}
```