# Crontab command set not working

Tags: macos, permissions, shell-script, cron

I'm trying to set up `crontab` to run a shell script, but for some reason, the script doesn't get executed. I'm on system with OS X 10.8.5.

**`crontab` file**

```
0 12 * * 1 /absolute/path/to/myscript.sh
0 15 * * 2 /absolute/path/to/myscript.sh
30 10 * * 3 /absolute/path/to/myscript.sh
0 18 * * 3 /absolute/path/to/myscript.sh
30 10 * * 4 /absolute/path/to/myscript.sh
```

**myscript.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /Users/me/Documents/targetfile/ && git add . && git commit -m "Added notes for $(date)" && git push -u origin master
```

The script runs fine when it's launched manually, using a shell, but produces only these entries in Console.app:

```
launchctl: launchctl: Dubious permissions on file (skipping): /Library/LaunchAgents/com.adobe.AAM.Updater-1.0.plist
```

I have executed `chmod 777 myscript.sh` as well as the error-raising `.plist` file, but to no avail.

EDIT: `ls -l /Library/LaunchAgents/com.adobe.AAM.Updater-1.0.plist` outputs:

```
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root  wheel  612  2 Aug 18:57 /Library/LaunchAgents/com.adobe.AAM.Updater-1.0.plist
```

and `ls -ld /Library/LaunchAgents`

```
drwxr-xr-x  22 root  wheel  748 10 Sep 21:12 /Library/LaunchAgents
```

I did set up the crontab using root, and I have no idea whatsoever what that plist has to do with the script I'm trying to do.

What's wrong with my setup?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the output of `ls -l /Library/LaunchAgents/com.adobe.AAM.Updater-1.0.plist` as well as `ls -ld /Library/LaunchAgents` (assuming OS X `ls` works similar to GNU ls). Also, please explain how it is related to your script.

Comment: Possibly relevant: [http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/63857/launchctldubious-permissions-on-file-problem-installing-jenkins](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/63857/launchctldubious-permissions-on-file-problem-installing-jenkins) as well as [http://superuser.com/questions/238469/launchctl-dubious-ownership-on-file-skipping-mac-os-x](http://superuser.com/questions/238469/launchctl-dubious-ownership-on-file-skipping-mac-os-x)

Comment: Are other commands (like for example `* * * * * say a`) run from crontab? Did you try adding the command to the user's crontab?

Comment: `* * * * * say a` doesn't work when crontab is edited from root or user.

Comment: I wonder if the "dubious" permission error is given because there are *too many* permissions: Try 755 instead of 777

Comment: I changed the permissions to `755` for all the files involved. Nothing shows up in the console, but the command doesn't fire off.

I've now tried this with a GUI frontend, CronniX, and the command, `echo "Hello World!"`. Still nothing.

Comment: echo will not show up as an output of cron.  You could `touch /tmp/unique_filename` if you want evidence that the cron was running successfully.

Comment: Alright, I've figured it out. The text editor I use was wrongly configured to insert several spaces instead of a tab when I pressed the tab key.

Answer (score 0):

add to your crontab line : &>/tmp/myscript.log

for example :

0 12 * * 1 /absolute/path/to/myscript.sh &>/tmp/myscript.log

and wait for the script to executes and check the myscript log, I assume that the possible errors will be " git command not found " or " cd command not found" , if that was the case then you have to locate the full path of theses commands via 'find' or 'locate' and enter its full path, for example instead of `cd` use `/path_to_cd/cd` etc..